# cordova app launch native app with custom parameter

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I've an **Android** and **iOS** app with source code. These 2 apps are created by another vendor. I need to use my **cordova** app to pass in some custom parameters to thesw 2 apps and launch it.

for **cordova** app, how do we launch native app with parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Use intent to launch the Android app while use Custom URL Scheme to start the iOS one. Both of them can take parameter.

1 As you have the source code the two apps, you need to edit the androidManifest.xml and info.plist respectively, allowing the native apps to recognize your intention.

2 change the source code for each platform, making them do something special with the parameters.

reference link
Android
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

iOS
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html